# Mysql query with $_POST treatment

Tags: php, mysql, post, if-statement

I have a query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dados_kirin WHERE BEBIDA = '$_POST[t_bebida]' AND UF = '$_POST[t_UF]' AND CANAL = '$_POST[t_canal]' AND ANO = '$_POST[t_ano]'";
```

The query  above will not run OK, because t_bebida can be ALL.

I want to treat the $_POST. If it is ALL, it must be translated to *.

I've tried something like:

```
= $_POST[t_bebida] = $bebida;
if ($bebida = "Todos") {
    $bebida = '*'
    };
```

But dreamweaver tells me that it's wrong.

Someone know a way to do that?

I'm using PHP and MYSQL.

Thank you guys!

**UPDATE:**

I've tried this:

```
$t_bebida = $_POST[t_bebida];
if ($t_bebida == "Todos") {
    $t_bebida = '*';
    }
```

But I've made a horrible query structure.

I think that what I need, is:

if ($t_bebida == "Todos"), don't use BEBIDA in WHERE clause.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dados_kirin WHERE BEBIDA = '$_POST[t_bebida]' AND UF = '$_POST[t_UF]' AND CANAL = '$_POST[t_canal]' AND ANO = '$_POST[t_ano]'";
```

**UPDATE 2**

> I am sorry, but this question have some MySQL structural errors in query. Thanks
>   for all the efforts to try help me out. Meanwhile I'll fix it.

Comment: And the semicolon is placed redundantly, belongs behind the inner assignment. That would satisfy PHPs syntax and possibly Dreamweaver.

Comment: Not only are the mysql_* functions deprecated, as Christian Mark mentioned,but the way you have your query set up is wide open for sql injection attacks.  Sanitize any input coming from the user.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple error in your syntax:

```
$_POST[t_bebida] = $bebida;
if ($bebida = "Todos") {
    $bebida = '*'
    };
```

1st: variable assignment of your `$bebida`:

```
$bebida = $_POST[t_bebida];
```

2nd: $_POST variable should be:

```
$bebida = $_POST['t_bebida']; //assuming that in your form you have an input name=t_bebida
```

3rd: In your if statement, this should be:

```
if ($bebida == "Todos") {
```

4th: Missing semicolon on your expression:

```
$bebida = '*';
             ^ here
```

5th: You don't have to put semicolon on your if statement's closing curly braces. Now here's the final version:

```
$bebida = $_POST['t_bebida'];
if ($bebida == "Todos") {
    $bebida = '*';
}
```

### **Update**

I also noticed that the `$_POST` variable in your query is *improperly* accessed like in the 2nd item. Also you have to sanitized your post variables to prevent SQL Injection.

---

Just in case:

Note that the mysql extension [is now **deprecated** and will be removed sometime in the future](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). That's because it is ancient, full of bad practices and lacks some modern features. Don't use it to write new code. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks @Christian, I'll read about PDO or mysqli, I don't even know it.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison operator is wrong. You're using = which is an assignment operator. In your example it will always be true. You need to use == which is a comparison operator.

```
if ($bebida = "Todos") {
```

should be

```
if ($bebida == "Todos") {
```

Comment: Thanks @John, but i still have the problem.